# Packed storage with BLAS function

Tags: fortran, lapack, blas

I want to calculate A*x with A lower triangle matrix and x the vector. For example:

```
     1  0  0
A =  2  4  0
     3  5  6
```

with packed storage

```
 A = (/ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6/)
```

and

```
 X = (/1, 1, 1/)
```

Now I want to do A*x with BLAS function, shoud I tranform A back to be a 3x3 matrix? If not, could you please give me some hint? (I know in memory of fortran array, A is contiguously stored)

Comment: Well, BLAS does provide some support for sparse matrix operations, and your favourite search engine will help you find the documentation.  But a lot of us don't think that a matrix is sparse until ~<5% of entries are non-zero so not many of us (who is this *us* I keep referring to ?) would keep your `A` in compressed storage anyway, not until the pressure on available RAM got a lot higher.

Comment: BLAS has matrix-vector multiply for triangular matrix in packed form. We'd probably need much more detail on your real (rather than example) system to be able to advise further on whether you're better off unpacking first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved by checking: http://www.icl.utk.edu/~mgates3/docs/lapack.html

```
program main

  implicit none
  integer :: n
  real*8, allocatable, dimension(:) :: x
  real*8, allocatable, dimension(:) :: A

  n = 3
  allocate(A(n*(n+1)/2))
  allocate(x(n))
  A = 1.0d0
  x = 1.0d0

  ! x will be updated as A*x
  call dtpmv('L', 'N', 'N', n, A, x, 1)

  deallocate(A)
  deallocate(x)

end program main
```